Vector Overlay-Clip tool error
When I try to clip two layers in QGIS, it generates an error. I made sure the layers are in the same EPSG, but it hasn't worked. Also, I have changed the layer to a shapefile or just left it as a TAB, but I have not succeeded.
The error is:

Feature (1) from "..." has invalid geometry, please fix the geometry or change the "invalid feature filtering" option for this input or globally in Processing settings.

How can I solve the error?

what program are you using? also have you tried fixing the invalid geometries in your layer(s)?

The error message seem pretty clear on the cause and offert to option to solve the problem, did you try any of them ?

Try the Fix geometries tool

If @Bera ’s suggestion does not work, you can also buffer all features by a 0-distance (that usually helps with invalid geometries)
